# Open API for E numbers information

Tags: food

Is there any API or open database for E-numbers data that includes information about e-number status (dangerous  / not recommended / valid)?

I've found only this database: https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/foods_system/main/?event=substances.search&substances.pagination=1

But it doesn't include the status info.